# Jackson JSON not working with CXF

Tags: json, cxf, jackson

The JacksonJsonProvider is not working with CXF.

CXF v2.6.0 
Jackson v2.1.2 (com.fasterxml.jackson) 
RESTClient (for testing)

I do have the provider configured like below in beans.xml.

```
<bean id="jacksonMapper" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper">
    <property name="dateFormat">
    <bean class="java.text.SimpleDateFormat">
    <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ">     </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
   </property>
</bean>

<bean id="jacksonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider">
    <property name="mapper" ref="jacksonMapper" />
</bean>
```

in     jaxrs:server.....>

```
<jaxrs:providers>
<ref bean="jaxbProvider" />
<ref bean="jacksonProvider" />                        
</jaxrs:providers>

</jaxrs:server>
```

The application gets deployed without any issues, it gives good JSON while I give the request as "application/xml" and the response as "application/json".

When I try to give JSON in request by setting Content-Type=application/json I'm facing the 500 Internal Server Error

The request is getting logged in the log file thru CXF-logging.

The request is not at all landing in the service implementation class of my webservice.

The JSON in request body is :

```
{"SearchOrdersRequest":{"LoginCredentials":{"AppId":"BookStore","Username":"myuser","Password":"abcd1234","SecurityToken":"Vcvx45YilzX1"},"SearchHeader":{"SearchCategory":"Rep","FilterLogic":"1 AND 2","SearchParams":{"Field":"Order Number (s)","Operator":"EQUALS","Values":"600045335"}}}}
```

Any immediate help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you get the solution of this issue?

Answer (score 4):

In [CXF documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html) , you can see where you need to add json provider and include a dependency. But, I still getting errors when I tried to add jackson instead of jettison, after some hours I figured that you need to include one more jackson dependency.

1. Add JSON provider

   ```
   <jaxrs:providers>
       <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJaxbJsonProvider" />
   </jaxrs:providers>
   ```
2. Add dependencies

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-xc</artifactId>
       <version>1.9.12</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
       <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
       <version>1.9.12</version>
   </dependency>
   ```

Comment: this still valid after 2 years

Comment: how to repleace jaxrs:providers with pure javaconfig (no xml?)

Answer (score 3):

As I undertood you, your application produces and consumes xml and json format. So, first of all. Make it sure that your cxf resource endpoint are able to do it.

```
@Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
```

Otherwise your request won't find any resource implementation. (at these line at class level or method level)

Then if this is not enough check out this jackson cxf integration:

```
<bean id="jsonProvider" class="com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json.JacksonJsonProvider" />
<bean id="jsonContextResolver" class="net.sf.gazpachoquest.rest.support.JacksonContextResolver" />
```

Also

```
 <jaxrs:server id="services" address="/">
   <jaxrs:providers>
      <ref bean="jsonProvider" />
      <ref bean="jsonContextResolver" />
     </jaxrs:providers>
  </jaxrs:server>
```

The context resolver the class where the mapper is defined:

```
@Provider
public class JacksonContextResolver implements ContextResolver<ObjectMapper> {

    private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public JacksonContextResolver() {
        /*
         * Register JodaModule to handle Joda DateTime Objects.
         * https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-datatype-jsr310
         */
        mapper.registerModule(new JSR310Module());
        mapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_EMPTY);
        mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS, false);

    }

    @Override
    public ObjectMapper getContext(Class<?> arg0) {
        return mapper;
    }
}
```

And just in case you deploy your application into a j2ee container, you may require a application config class:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class ApplicationConfig extends javax.ws.rs.core.Application{

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        // add here your resources
        classes.add(JacksonContextResolver.class);
        classes.add(JacksonJsonProvider.class);
        ...
        return classes;
    }
```

Hope this help.

Comment: Saved my day ! Thanks :)

Comment: What's the maven dependency to import net.sf.gazpachoquest.rest.support.JacksonContextResolver, unfortunately, I can't find it! thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: The code of net.sf.gazpachoquest.rest.support.JacksonContextResolver is printed in the post above. Starts where it says: the class where the mapper is defined:

Answer (score 0):

Some time ago I had problem with a json request when I had not jettison library in classpath. 
Check http://www.javatips.net/blog/2012/02/cxf-restful-tutorial tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use jackson library by overriding jettison, you need to configure jacksonprovider like following

```
<bean id="jacksonJsonProvider" class="com.student.CustomJsonProvider"/>

<jaxrs:providers> 
  <ref bean="jacksonJsonProvider" /> 
</jaxrs:providers>
```

Answer (score 0):

In normal circumstances if you deploy to a EE server by simply adding that dependency the provider had to be automatically discovered and used (I tested width TomEE 7):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.6 </version>
</dependency>
```

But be careful to use the correct version. CFX guide suggests a Jackson JAX-RS provider that is only compatible with Jackson 1 and not for Jackson 2. Look [at that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38168507/getcontext-method-of-customcontextresolver-is-not-called-by-jackson/42937480#42937480) for more details

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you are using the jackson library with group `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs`, the server is expecting the request in following format:

```
{
  "LoginCredentials": {
    "AppId" : "BookStore",
    "Username":"myuser",
    "Password":"abcd1234",
    "SecurityToken":"Vcvx45YilzX1"
  },
  "SearchHeader":{
    "SearchCategory":"Rep",
    "FilterLogic":"1 AND 2",
    "SearchParams":{
      "Field":"Order Number (s)",
      "Operator":"EQUALS",
      "Values":"600045335"
    }
  }
}
```

But your client will be sending in following format:

```
{
  "SearchOrdersRequest": {
    "LoginCredentials": {
      "AppId" : "BookStore",
      "Username":"myuser",
      "Password":"abcd1234",
      "SecurityToken":"Vcvx45YilzX1"
    },
    "SearchHeader":{
      "SearchCategory":"Rep",
      "FilterLogic":"1 AND 2",
      "SearchParams":{
        "Field":"Order Number (s)",
        "Operator":"EQUALS",
        "Values":"600045335"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It seems to be the issue with this `fasterxml` version of library only. Using the library with group `org.codehaus.jackson` will fix the issue. Both request and response will be without root element.

So you need to replace the following maven dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs-json-provider</artifactId>
  <version>2.9.3</version>
</dependency>
```

with

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-jaxrs</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
```

I checked that the library mentioned in the cxf docs (https://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-data-bindings.html#JAX-RSDataBindings-Jackson) is also the one with `com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs` but if you check the classes that are mentioned there in beans are from `org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs`. So I think this is a mistake in docs and needs correction.

Comment: The closing comment is still valid, this still seems to be a documentation issue.